# Advantages and Disadvantages of using ttf file in Codenameone application

Tags: codenameone

Please what are the advantages and disadvantages of using ttf fonts in Codenameone application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disadvantages may be:**

- Some ttf font sizes may not look great on different devices if your sizes don't fall within small, medium and large.
- Few extra kilobytes add to your overall app size (Not really bad).

**Advantages includes but not limited to:**

- Ability to customize your app look and feel by using any font of your
  choice. Supported on all platforms.
- Allow to have thousands of icons (even flat logos) without having a
  huge app through fonticon.
- Reduction in app size by using fonticon (ttf font) to generate icons
  and even logos.
- Easy Integration.
- Supports having different font variant and size like light, regular,
  bold and so on...
- Allows using millimetres for a very large font.

Codenameone now supports using platform native fonts on iOS and Android.
Read more about the new native fonts [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/good-looking-by-default-native-fonts-simulator-detection-more.html)